# Wildfly/Slf4j integration issues

Tags: java, logging, wildfly, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to integrate SLF4J in a struts application built in many layers:

commun-module,
web-module,
service-module, etc ...

Every module is using a logging class called **TraceurProxy** defined below:

```
   public class TraceurProxy {

        private Logger logger;

        public TraceurProxy(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Class classe) {
            this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(classe);
        }

        public boolean isDebugActive() {
            return this.logger.isDebugEnabled();
        }

        public boolean isInfoActive() {
            return this.logger.isInfoEnabled();
        }

        public boolean isWarnActive() {
            return this.logger.isWarnEnabled();
        }

        public boolean isErrorActive() {
            return this.logger.isErrorEnabled();
        }

    //  public boolean isFatalActive() {
    //      return this.logger.isFatalEnabled();
    //  }

        public void debug(Object object) {
            this.logger.debug(object.toString());
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentEventCode(InformationHelper.EXTERNAL_TRACEUR_CODE);
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentTempsEcoule("");
        }

        public void debug(Object object, Throwable throwable) {
            this.logger.debug(object.toString(), throwable);
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentEventCode(InformationHelper.EXTERNAL_TRACEUR_CODE);
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentTempsEcoule("");
        }

        public void info(Object object) {
            this.logger.info(object.toString());
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentEventCode(InformationHelper.EXTERNAL_TRACEUR_CODE);
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentTempsEcoule("");
        }

        public void info(Object object, Throwable throwable) {
            this.logger.info(object.toString(), throwable);
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentEventCode(InformationHelper.EXTERNAL_TRACEUR_CODE);
            TraceurHelper.defineCurrentTempsEcoule("");
        }

    }
```

This class is called everywhere in the application [every module] to manage logs.

The problem that I'm facing now is that I wish for the logs to be externalized out of the application for production deployment purposes. I used the logBack approach as an implementation to the SLF4J standard by defining the following file:

**logback.xml**

```
    <configuration debug="true" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <property name="LOG_PATH" value="C:/logs"/>
    <property name="LOG_ARCHIVE" value="${LOG_PATH}/archive"/>
    <timestamp key="timestamp-by-second" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>
    <appender name="rollingFileLogger" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <file>${LOG_PATH}/logfile-${timestamp-by-second}.log</file>
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_ARCHIVE}/rollingfile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <maxFileSize>3MB</maxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger level="ALL" name="*.*.*">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger level="ALL" name="*.*.*">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <root level="ALL">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFileLogger"/>
    </root>
    </configuration>
```

I put this config file outside the project classpath for maintenance purposes and I used the following property as **VM argument in eclipse** to inform **Wildfly** about the config file location **-Dlogback.configurationFile=C:/logs/Logback.xml**, yet after the startup phase, I find nothing after invoking an HTTP request, no files created, no logs appended. It's like Wildfly is completely ignoring my configuration and only logs **server.log**.

Here are my dependencies:

```
           <dependency>
              <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
              <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
              <version>1.1.7</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
              <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
              <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
              <version>1.1.7</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.25</version>
           </dependency>
```

As I've said before, my application architecture contains many projects and I put the dependencies and the **TraceurProxy** definition in the **common-module** because it's used by all front modules like the **web** module.

Thanks in advance for any solution, I'm blocked.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use logback rather than the logging subsystem to configure logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by taking the following actions.

1. I created the jboss-deployment-structure.xml as follows

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
       <sub-deployment name="pfi-web.war">
           <exclusions>
               <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
               <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
               <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
               <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
               <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
               <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
               <module name="org.slf4j" />
               <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
           </exclusions>
       </sub-deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
2. I had to put it under EAR/META-INF folder.